# Error inflating class fragment android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-layout-inflater

Я делаю учебную программку в которой есть некий список вопросов на которые можно ответить да или нет. В зависимости от ответа текст с вопросом меняет цвет. Результаты должны быть выведены в отдельной активити. Мне подсказали использовать фрагменты чтобы сохранить то какой цвет у текста с вопросом но у меня есть с ними ошибка Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment

Вот код:

```
MainActivity:
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   // public static String TAG = "MYLOG_main_activity";
    public static String KEY = "KEY";
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    Context mContext;
    Button mResult;
    public static int[] iResult;

    public static void MyReceiver(int[] result)
    {
        iResult = result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            iResult = savedInstanceState.getIntArray(KEY);
        }
        mResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.result);
        mResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View asv) {if(iResult != null) {
               /* Intent intent1 = new Intent("Intent");
                intent1.putExtra("message", iResult);
                intent1.setAction("broadcast");
                sendBroadcast(intent1);
*/

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Result.receiver(iResult);
            }

            }
        });
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        ArrayList<Ask> asks = new ArrayList<>();
        asks.add(0,new Ask(0,R.drawable.image1,R.string.one));
        asks.add(1,new Ask(1,R.drawable.image2,R.string.two));
        asks.add(2,new Ask(2,R.drawable.image3,R.string.three));
        asks.add(3,new Ask(3,R.drawable.image4,R.string.four));
        asks.add(4,new Ask(4,R.drawable.image5,R.string.five));
        //iResult = new int[asks.size()];
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(asks);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putIntArray(KEY, iResult);
    }
}
```

RVAdapter:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by 1 on 2.09.2016.
 */
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.CardViewHolder>{
    public static final String TAG = "MYLOG_RVAdapter";
    List<Ask> asks;
    int[] iResult;
    RVAdapter(List<Ask> asks) {
        this.asks = asks;
            iResult = new int[asks.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < asks.size(); i++) {
                iResult[i] = 0;
            }

    }
        @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false); //На эту строку ругается
            Log.d(TAG,"onCreateViewHolder");
            return new CardViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return asks.size();
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onAttachedToRecyclerView");
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {


       holder.mButtonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.mTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.No);
                iResult[position] = 2;
                MainActivity.MyReceiver(iResult);
            }
        });
        holder.mButtonYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.mTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Yes);
                iResult[position] = 1;
                MainActivity.MyReceiver(iResult);
            }
        });
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                holder.mTextView.setText(R.string.one);
                holder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.mTextView.setText(R.string.two);
                holder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.mTextView.setText(R.string.three);
                holder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
                break;
            case 3:
                holder.mTextView.setText(R.string.four);
                holder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);
                break;
            case 4:
                holder.mTextView.setText(R.string.five);
                holder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image5);
                break;
        }

        Log.d(TAG,"onBindViewHolder");
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(position));

    }

    public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mImageView;
        TextView mTextView;
        CardView mCardVew;
        Button mButtonYes;
        Button mButtonNo;
        public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mButtonNo = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.No);
            mButtonYes = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Yes);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mCardVew = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

            Log.d(TAG,"CardViewHolder");


        }
    }
}
```

TextFragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by 1 on 04.10.2016.
 */
public class TextFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
activity_main:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vkramarenko.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/result"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Yes"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/result">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/no"
                android:id="@+id/No"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
  <fragment
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:name="com.vkramarenko.myapplication.TextFragment"
      android:id="@+id/textFragment"
      android:layout_above="@+id/No"
      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/No" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/yes"
                android:id="@+id/Yes"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/No" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/image1"
                android:contentDescription=""
                android:layout_above="@+id/textFragment"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/No" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте в `item.xml` заменить `android:name="com.vkramarenko.myapplication.TextFragment"` на `class="com.vkramarenko.myapplication.TextFragment"`.

Comment: Это не помогает я уже пробовал(кстати какая между ними разница?)

Comment: Они, в принципе, взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: И все же код пока не работает. До того как я добавил фрагмент все было в порядке.

Comment: полный стактрейс ошибки в студию!

Comment: tools:context=".MainActivity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я много нервов убил на фрагменты и решил делать динамически. Меняешь свой код в разметке активити

```
<fragment
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name="com.vkramarenko.myapplication.TextFragment"
  android:id="@+id/textFragment"
  android:layout_above="@+id/No"
  android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/No" />
```

На фреймлэйаут

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frgmCont"   <!--по этому id будем обращаться-->
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ТвоеАктивити"
>
```

Пример разметки фрагмента: frame.xml у меня оно все окно закрывает собой

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.бла-бла.бла.КлассФрейма">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
```

Класс фрейма создаешь мастером и там самое основное

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // R.layout.frame - имя твоего xml для фрейма
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

А дальше для отображения фрейма в момент, когда тебе нужно его отобразить (по онклик или при создании активити:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.frgmCont,new КонструкторФрагмента() ).commit();
```

new КонструкторФрагмента() можно заменить на Фрагмент.newInstance (мастер создает этот метод)

если используешь библиотеки совместимости, то 
getSupportedFragmentManager()

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это смысл задания - использовать  фрагменты. У меня его просто не примут. Хотя в условии нету такого, но у меня такой  веселый преподаватель который сначала даст помучатся, а потом может поможет